# Blazor UI with dynamic formulas input which can be stored in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, blazor

I'm developing a C# application, the front-end is a Blazor app running Radzen components while the back-end is classic C# combined with MySQL db over .Net5 framework.

My goal is to create a web UI where the user can create a basic arithmetic formulas, for ex:

> ( "KWH value of meter xyz123" - "KWH value of meter abc789" ) / 2

Note, the above KWH values are stored in the MySQL db and have to be retrieved first, the above formula should be also saved in a MySQL db because it will retrieved and re-used later by some automatic background process...

I'm not sure what will be the best MySQL table format to save the formula, also, I'm not sure what is the best tool to parse the user formula input to something computable in C#.

is there a open source NuGet?

Are the native .Net5 tools enough for the job?

Comment: *what will be the best MySQL table format to save the formula* As I understand the formulas may be: stored, retrieved, deleted, maybe edited. None processing on MySQL side will be performed... so - TEXT datatype column which stores the formula text, and needed additional columns (SERIAL PK, user ID, formula custom name, custom explanation, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

1. Save as text (trivial part)
2. "I'm not sure what is the best tool to parse the user formula input to something computable in C#."
   To parse this, use ANTLR. (https://www.antlr.org/) There is a C# version of it. You will need to understand the basics of computer grammar. There are many Github projects which implement a basic calculator in C#. However, remember that the whole activity is non-trivial.

If you are not married to Radzen, check out Syncfusion components. They allow basic formula calculation on data tables via the PivotTable component.

https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/pivot-table/calculated-field

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I will check this out, I don't have relevant code examples yet, I was interested in ideas and opinions about how to do this task as good as possible. I'm using Radzen and not syncfusion because I prefer fully open source Nugets. I find it difficult to trust syncfusion long term, they say you can get their components for free but they force you to use a private KEY and they can change their mind any second about that...